# Is this graph a graceful tree?

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose we have a graph $G=(V,E)$ where $V=\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$ and $E$ consists of $n$ edges
in such a way that the set of absolute differences $\{|i-j||ij\in E\}$ is exactly the set
$\{1,\ldots,n\}$. In other words: if $G$ is a tree, it is a graceful tree.

But can we be sure that $G$ indeed is a tree? Why can't there be any cycles?

I think $G$ must be a tree, but I am missing the right approach to prove it. Any ideas for a proof? Counterexamples?

Comment: It'll be enough to prove that $G$ is connected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$G$ doesn't have to be a tree. For example let $n=4$ and let the edges be $02, 03, 23, 04$.